# Create Single Menu(according to singleton pattern) for whole application in android

Tags: android

I want to create one menu for whole application in android. let suppose if the menu is not created then it will create and if menu is already created then it will show that menu which is already created . I don't want to create menu again and again. just create one time and use that object in whole application.

thanks in Advance

Comment: Then make a single activity with fragments .

Comment: how to start ? do u have any tutorial regarding this problem?

Comment: http://viewpagerindicator.com/